# Ember Data - Find by ID and using filters

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any way to use `find` method to request a URL like this?

`http://awesomedomain.com/api/models/1/?foo=bar`

Right now, if I use `Model.find({id: 1, foo: 'bar'})`, it's automatically using `findQuery` and the URL requested is `api/models/?id=1&foo=bar`, which is triggering a different method in the backend.

Another option would be to address this at the backend routing, but I would like to know if it can be achieved inside **Ember**.

Comment: what is your server backend for this ember app? rails/django ?

Comment: I am using Yii framework (PHP), but the real question is if it can be addressed at frontend level.

Comment: just looking at the source it would appear that isn't supported out of the box as you only get 1 or the other (id lookup OR query_string lookup). it might be worth making a pull request for something like this on the github site if an issue does not already exist

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you should be able to provide something like this:

```
Your.Model.find(1,{foo:"bar"})
```

Right now, the only thing you can do is:

```
Your.Model.find(1)
```

Then in your RestAdapter, override the ajax request manually to add the hash/query param:

```
Your.RESTAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  url: 'http://awesomedomain.com/api/models',
  ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
    hash.url = url;
    hash.type = type;
    hash.dataType = 'json';
    hash.contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    hash.context = this;
    hash.data = {foo:"bar"};
    jQuery.ajax(hash);
  }
});
```